# how to intercept an external url?

Tags: angular

```
...
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
     console.log(' [loader.interceptor.ts:24]', request.url);
```

- back urls are displayed correctly
- urls to: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups are not displayed and therefore do not pass through the intercept.

my goal is to display a spinner for the back and urls to graph.microsoft.com

Comment: Please provide more information. What do you mean by `back urls are displayed correctly` ? And what do you mean that `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups` are not displayed correctly? where are they not being displayed correctly? why does it matter?

Comment: - with api url, console.log(' [loader.interceptor.ts:24]', request.url);   //  displaying url

- with: https://graph.microsoft...... console.log(' [loader.interceptor.ts:24]', request.url); //  is  not displaying

** so that means that api urls go into the interceptor but not microsoft graph urls.